# heroku create ができなくなりました

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

`heroku create` を実行するとメールアドレスとパスワードの入力を求められ（先日までは求められませんでした！）それぞれ入力すると下記のメッセージが表示されます。

```
Please specify a version along with Heroku's API MIME type. For example, `Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3`.
```

なお、heroku のサイトへは普通にログインもできます。
何かご存知の方、ぜひおしえてください！

環境：
MacOS 10.13.2
Rails 5.1.4

Comment: ターミナルで`heroku --version`を実行した結果を追記していただけますか。heroku cliの問題が疑われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！結果は以下の通りでした。

heroku-gem/3.41.5 (x86_64-darwin16) ruby/2.3.1
You have no installed plugins.
WARNING: Toolbelt v3.43.9999 update available.

Comment: ご提案ありがとうございました！解決しました！
herokuのgemを削除して、toolbeltのインストーラからインストールしましたら解決できました！ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

コメントで頂いたアドバイスを元に `heroku --version` を実行したところ、以下のように表示されました。

```
heroku-gem/3.41.5 (x86_64-darwin16) ruby/2.3.1
You have no installed plugins.
WARNING: Toolbelt v3.43.9999 update available.
```

heroku の gem を削除して、toolbelt のインストーラからインストールすることで解決できました。

---

*この投稿は [@しょうねん さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40911/heroku-create-%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8f%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f#comment41736_40911) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*